# How do I resize a div automatically to the size of its contents when the contents of the div have changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, resize

At the moment, I have this DIV with a registration form centered over the page. The contents of the DIV come from an ascx-page. This is done nicely.
Now, if the user tries to fill in a name that's not unique, an error message is added by some jQuery next to the username field. This breaks the layout of the DIV, since the contents now are wider than they used to be.
So I've googled my way into this, but I can't find a solution for this.

Can anyone help me find a nice way to do this (pseudo HTML/js):

```
<div id="myCenteredDiv" onChangeContents="resizeToNewSize()">
  <!-- div contents -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeToNewSize() {
    $("#myCenteredDiv").animateToSize($("#myCenteredDiv").contentWidth, 
      $("#myCenteredDiv").contentHeight);
  }
</script>
```

I'm looking for the "onChangeContents" method (and/or event) and the "div.contentWidth" property.

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

**update: trying to explain the problem more clearly**

Let's say I have this DIV:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <form ...>
    Enter your name: <input id="txtYourName" type="text" name="YourName" value="" />
    <span id="errorYourName"></span>
    <input type="submit" ... />
  </form>
</div>
```

And let's say I have this snippet of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtYourName").live("blur", function() {
    if (validateInput($("#txtYourName").val())) {
      $("#errorYourName").html("");
      // entry 1
    } else {
      // entry 2
      $("#errorYourName").html("This name is not valid.");
    }
  });
});
```

...where `validateInput(value)` returns `true` for a valid value.

Well now. The SimpleModal plugin takes the div and places it centered on the page, with a certain width and height it somehow reads off of the contents of the div. So the div isn't wider than the input box, since the span is empty at the moment.

When the input box loses focus, an error message is put into the span. This then breaks the layout of the div.

I could put code into `entry 1` that resizes the div back with an animation to some size when the error message has been cleared, and code into `entry 2` that resizes the div to a bigger size so the error message will fit.

But what I'd like best is a way to tell if the contents within the div have changed, and fit the div accordingly, animated and automatically.

Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: have you tried setting the css mid-width property instead of the width property?

Comment: Is this div bounded by another div of fixed width?

Comment: How is the DIV styled?  Is it using fixed dimensions?

Comment: I'm using the SimpleModal jQuery plugin. Not sure whether it uses a fixed div, but I can resize it using animate() nicely.

Comment: Simplemodal plugin: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: The problem is more, I suspect, that the values returned by contentWidth and contentHeight are not changing when the content changes. Is that correct?

Comment: @Lazarus True, the div doesn't get wider, so I hope I don't have to check on all fields in the div if their content changes... (Too much of a js-newbie, me.)

Comment: @Lazarus div.contentWidth is pseudo. I don't know what I should call.

Comment: An ugly workaround is that I call the resize-method any time an error is thrown. It looks very nice in the browser, but I wouldn't want to be the maintainance programmer on THAT code...

Comment: The CSS:

element.style {
display:block;
height:130px;
left:436.5px;
position:fixed;
top:185.5px;
width:350px;
z-index:1002;
}
#simplemodal-container {
background-color:#EEEEEE;
border:8px solid #444444;
padding:12px;
}

I suspect the SimpleModal plugin to alter these values though.

Comment: oops.. I just deleted my previous comment about what CSS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used SimpleModal, but from the examples on their site it looks like you can set the container CSS. If you want the height to adjust, try setting the height to `auto`

```js
$("#sample").modal({
  containerCss:{
    backgroundColor:"#fff",
    borderColor:"#0063dc",
    height:450,
    padding:0,
    width:830
  }
});
```

Although the example doesn't have it, I'd think you need to add `px` after the height and width in quotes (e.g. `"450px"`).

---

Ok here is another idea. Maybe this is too much, but add a hidden input field:

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <form ...>
    Enter your name: <input id="txtYourName" type="text" name="YourName" value="" />
    <span id="errorYourName"></span>
    <input type="submit" ... />
    <input id="updated" type="hidden" />
  </form>
</div>
```

then attach a change event which is triggered at the same time you update the error message.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtYourName").live("blur", function() {
    if (validateInput($("#txtYourName").val())) {
      $("#errorYourName").html("");
      // entry 1
    } else {
      // entry 2
      $("#errorYourName").html("This name is not valid.");
      $("#updated").trigger('change');
    }
  });
  $("#updated").change(function(){
    // resize the modal window & reposition it
  })
});
```

This is untested and it may be going overboard, but I don't see an update function in SimpleModal.

---

**Update** : Sorry I figured out that blur isn't supported with live event. So I did some further testing and came up with a working demo. I posted it in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.me/b5c562cf996a553267b7d363daed662d) (ignore the included simpleModal code at the bottom). Here is the essential code

CSS

```css
#myDiv { line-Height: 25px; }
#simplemodal-container { background-color:#444; border:8px solid #777; padding: 12px; }
.simplemodal-wrap { overflow: hidden !important; }
.error { color: #f00; display: none; }
input { float: right; }
```

HTML

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <form>
    What is your name: <input id="txtYourName" type="text" name="YourName" value="" /><br>
    <div id="errorYourName" class="error">This name isn't Arthur.</div>

    What is your quest: <input id="txtYourQuest" type="text" name="YourQuest" value="" /><br>
    <div id="errorYourQuest" class="error">This quest must be for the Grail.</div>

    What is your favorite color: <input id="txtYourColor" type="text" name="YourColor" value="" /><br>
    <div id="errorYourColor" class="error">Sorry, you must like red or blue.</div>

    What is the air speed velocity of an unladen swallow:<br>
    Type:
    <select>
     <option>African</option>
     <option>European</option>
    </select>
    <input id="txtYourGuess" type="text" name="YourGuess" value="" /><br>
    <div id="errorYourGuess" class="error">This guess stinks.</div>
    <hr>
    <input id="submitMe" type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myDiv").modal({
   containerCss:{
    height: '165px',
    width: '350px'
   }
 })
 $("#txtYourName").focus();

 addValidate('#txtYourName','Arthur','#errorYourName');
 addValidate('#txtYourQuest','Grail|grail','#errorYourQuest');
 addValidate('#txtYourColor','red|blue','#errorYourColor');
 addValidate('#txtYourGuess','11|24','#errorYourGuess'); // See http://www.style.org/unladenswallow/ ;)

  $("#myDiv form").change(function() {
   // This is called if there are any changes to the form... added here for an example
   // alert('Form change detected');
  });
})

function addValidate(el,valid,err){
 $(el).blur(function() {
  if ( $(el).val().length > 0 && !$(el).val().match(valid) ) {
   if ($(err).is(':hidden')) {
    $('#simplemodal-container').animate({'height': ($('#simplemodal-container').height() + 25) + 'px'},1000);
    $(err).slideDown(1000);
   }
  } else {
   // entry 2
   if ($(err).is(':visible')) {
    $('#simplemodal-container').animate({'height': ($('#simplemodal-container').height() - 25) + 'px'},1000);
    $(err).slideUp(1000);
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: I'll give that one a try. Thanks! I'll check back my result.

Comment: Pity, it doesn't work. It only makes the border blue, and the div very large (Firebug tells me 'auto' is undefined...). I'll update the question and I'll try to make clearer what I want. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Hopefully the question is more clear now. *keeps fingers crossed*

Comment: Okay. So SimpleModal computes height/width of the div and puts those values in element.style as hard values (e.g. "width: 366.5").
What I do now, is put "width: auto !important" in my css file. The div doesn't break the layout when the contents are resized.
Two things left to do: (1) animate the resizing, and (2) center the div on the page... (Why isn't "center: horizontal" part of the CSS standard? :-) )

Comment: I know what you mean about centering, but the modal window has a fixed position, so you can't use something simple like `margin: auto`. So why did you set the width to auto and not the height, wasn't the height causing problems? `height: auto !important`. Is it necessary to animate it?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't complete. I did set height to auto too. I've tried "$("#myDiv").change(function() { resizeAndReposition() });" but that doesn't quite do the trick. I can't see how a hidden input will do that... I'll give it a try though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh and animations are a "could have". It just looks real nice: <code>function resizeModal(desiredWidth, desiredHeight, callback) {
    $.modal.impl.d.container.animate(
        {
            height: desiredHeight, 
            width: desiredWidth,
            left: (window.innerWidth / 2) - (desiredWidth / 2), 
            top: (((window.innerHeight / 2) - (desiredHeight / 2)) - 20)
        }, 
        defaultTransitionDuration, 
        defaultAnimationType,
        callback
    );
}</code>

Comment: ok, I've posted a working demo here - it doesn't work perfectly in IE, but it's more working example that just needs a little tweeking (http://pastebin.me/b5c562cf996a553267b7d363daed662d)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I don't have my code with me here, but I'll try asap!

Answer (score 2):

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var originalFontSize = 12;

var sectionWidth = $('#sidebar').width();



$('#sidebar span').each(function(){

    var spanWidth = $(this).width();

    var newFontSize = (sectionWidth/spanWidth) * originalFontSize;

    $(this).css({"font-size" : newFontSize, "line-height" : newFontSize/1.2 + "px"});

});

});

</script>
```

div:

```
<div id="sidebar">

<span>fits the width of the parent</span><br />

<span>Hello</span><br />

<span>my</span><br />

<span>name</span><br />

<span>is</span><br />

<span>john</span><br />

<span>1</span><br />

<span>23</span><br />

<span>456</span><br />

<span>12345678910</span><br />

<span>the font size in the span adjusts to the width</span><br />

</id>
```

preview
http://jbdes.net/dev/js/fontsize.html

Answer (score 1):

Old fashioned tables are (still) great at centering things, fast, fluid and code free.

```
<table width=100% height=100%><tr><td align=center valign=center>
    <table><tr><td style="yourStyle">
        your Content
    </td></tr></table>
</td></tr></tabĺe>

CSS: HTML,BODY {height:100%; width:100%}
```