# getCanvas in flot ignores original dimensions given in div and respects browser Zoom level instead

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, flot

Possibly similar question:  [How do I resize a div automatically to the size of its contents when the contents of the div have changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749346/how-do-i-resize-a-div-automatically-to-the-size-of-its-contents-when-the-content?rq=1), but not the same.  i.e. can't seem to work out what I need out of that question.

**My situation:**

I am drawing charts using flot.  I then use flot.canvas module to basically convert the axis labels I have from on-screen to canvas, and later I digitize the entire canvas using `plot.getCanvas()` and save it to an image on disk to display later.

I have noticed that if at-the-time-of-canvas-conversion I set the Zoom Level of my browser (Mozilla Firefox) to 30%, the entire canvas is saved as a small file, ignoring the original div's dimensions.

So say my DIV is `<div id="flot_chart" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px"></div>`,
but image renders with sizes `{width: 300px, height: 180px}`, as below:

[image]

Graph still looks okay but this conversion does horrible things to the labels, when I try to display this image at original size.  In other words, zooming out in browser makes the converted image unusable.

But then I have noticed that when I zoom my browser's viewport to 400%, canvas image renders HUGE and labels look great as well.

**My question**

How do I get a original canvas resolution, regardless of in-browser Zoom Level?

My goal is to get a good rendition of the chart, and for me it means saving the canvas in an image that has enough resolution to be reused later, in different situations, where dynamic post-factum resizing is not an option (i.e. PDF)

- I use var `canvas = plot.getCanvas()` to get my canvas.  How do I render canvas to be of the size I want in pixels (to save as an image), regardless of user's browser Zoom Level?
- If I can't do above, can I dynamically resize viewport's zoom on Firefox, get my canvas, and size it back later?

**Demo Example**

From Flot's own example you can experience this by going to http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/canvas/index.html

- zoom out to 30%
- clear the checkbox under the graph
- check the checkbox under the graph
- zoom to normal 100% and observe canvas

(result does not look so great & that's what I get when I digitize my canvas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dang, you have tough questions...

It seems that flot is scaling down the canvas based on the `devicePixelRatio` and `backingStoreRatio`.  This is necessary for dense pixel screens (like on iPhones).  When you "zoom" the browser it seems that these calculations will also scale down the canvas.

For instance if I zoom to 25%, my placeholder is still at 400px, but the canvas is down to 100:

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; padding: 0px; position: relative;">
    <canvas class="flot-base" width="100" height="100" style="direction: ltr; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 400px; height: 400px;"></canvas>
```

With a little experimentation, it seems you can scale back up the canvas before you `toDataURL` it:

```
$( "#download" ).click(function() {
  var canvas = plot.getCanvas();
  $(canvas).attr('width', 400); // resize it to what you want
  $(canvas).attr('height',400);
  plot.setupGrid(); // redraw plot to new size
  plot.draw();
  var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  
  ...
});
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1iwQNJ0IOBof9xxdlm6?p=preview).  Zoom down to 25%, force a reload by clicking Stop/Run button and then download the image.  It should be 400x400 pixels.

Comment: what was the tough part?

Comment: @Dennis, figuring out why flot was shrinking down the canvas, had to dig through the source code.